# Joomla Login Validation to be fix

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, registration

I am using Joomla 1.5

Issues occur when I submit the form without entries and it showing the error on `index.php` page. I need to show the same validation error on login page, any recommend to fix this kind of issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must write validation code for login form and registration form "by yourself".
put your validation code in this path for login form:

```
JOOMLAROOT/components/com_user/views/login/tmpl/default_login.php
```

and for register form, this path:

```
JOOMLAROOT/components/com_user/views/register/tmpl/default.php
```

Comment: `<form action="#" method="post" name="com-login" id="com-form-login">` i am using in this action, its showing as action # in firebug, still the form is getting action. how it could be possible ? what to do to fix it ?

Comment: use this: <form action="<?php echo JRoute::_( 'index.php', true, $this->params->get('usesecure')); ?>" method="post" name="com-login" id="com-form-login" onsubmit="return validate();"> and at validate() function, put your validation code.

Comment: Unfortunately i need to replace this `index.php` to `index.php?option=com_contushdvideoshare&view=myvideos` ? Possible, but it not redirecting, more over i am trying to use simple validation for this form, not working initially. :( Following script i am using to validate `<script language="javascript">
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["com-login"]["username"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("username must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
}

</script>`

Comment: & Form action as `<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php', true, $this->params->get('usesecure')); ?>" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" name="com-login" id="com-form-login">
`. Any Help  ?

Comment: use this validation code: var username = document.getElementById('username').value; if(username == ""){alert('username is empty');}

Comment: Yeah Return false was missing there. Done :) Thanks .. :)